# running a python script that requires matplotlib gives: ImportError: undefined symbol: __libm_sse2_sincos

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, intel

A specific package that I'm trying to run is [fastStructure](http://rajanil.github.io/fastStructure/). After installing all the requirements (numpy, scipy, cython, gsl, matplotlib), when I try to execute the script I get the following error:

```
python distruct.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "distruct.py", line 2, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
  File "/data003/GIF/software/packages/python/2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 24, in <module>
    import matplotlib.colorbar
  File "/data003/GIF/software/packages/python/2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py", line 27, in <module>
    import matplotlib.artist as martist
  File "/data003/GIF/software/packages/python/2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 8, in <module>
    from transforms import Bbox, IdentityTransform, TransformedBbox, \
  File "/data003/GIF/software/packages/python/2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 35, in <module>
    from matplotlib._path import (affine_transform, count_bboxes_overlapping_bbox,
ImportError: /data003/GIF/software/packages/python/2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_path.so: undefined symbol: __libm_sse2_sincos
```

Does this mean that some of the requirements weren't properly installed? or Am I missing some of the basic packages that are supposed to be there on all computers?
If it helps I am on a large HPC cluster, running RHEL with intel processors.
I am unable to find any information about this error and I am unable to move forward. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Specifically,

```
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
```

is what causing this error.

Comment: How did you install matplotlib?  Is there a change it was built from source on one machine and is now being run on another machine?  It looks like it either wasn't built properly (botched update, maybe?) or you've changed some system libraries/architecture out from under it...

Comment: I installed it via pip. Specifically, pip install matplotlib==1.3.1

Comment: A  guess, but it looks like `matplotlib` was compiled with a version of `libm`, that has some vectorized implementations for sin/cos (e.g. MKL), and then run on a different machine that doesn't have the same `libm.so`. Or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` somehow changed between the installation and the later import of matplotlib, so it's not loading the correct `.so`.

Comment: Are you running the script on the front end or back end? On a lot of HPC machines the front end nodes have different environments from the compute nodes and the compilers are usually set up to compile for the compute nodes.

Comment: @rph, I re-installed matplotlib, and recompiled fastStructure, still get the same error. I am running it on headnode to test the installation (all packages were installed on headnode, in a group accessible directory). Also, all installations were performed back to back without changing any variables/lib paths.